# How to open a database encrypted with SQLCipher?

Tags: react-native, sqlite, sqlcipher, db-browser-sqlite, sqlitestudio

I created and encrypted a database with the package.(react-native-sqlcipher) I want to open this database with "DB Browser for SQLite" or "SQLite Studio". However, it doesn't open even though I enter the correct key. Is salt being added while encrypting the database? If so, where is salt stored?

Note: There is no problem with the Android application.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Ubuntu does not support it. I tried it on windows and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to check the version of your Sqlite database. The current version of DB Browser for SQLite will not open sqlCypher encrypted Sqlite database version 3.x, only 4.x. If you want to open old encrypted files you have to download an older version of DB Browser for SQLite, such as 3.10.1, check here:

For more information : https://sqlitebrowser.org/